# Textbox on ReportViewer (RDLC) not wrapping but forcing a page break

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, reportviewer, rdlc

Situation: My report uses several ReportViewer Textbox controls which grow and shrink, depending on the size of the bound text.  When the text in the ReportViewer textbox control is too long to fit on the current page, a page break occurs ***before*** the textbox and it is then wholly rendered in the next page.  This often results in a large empty gap at the bottom of the first page where the page break occurred.

I would prefer the textbox to wrap the text across both pages, rendering as much of the text as will fit on the current page and then wrapping the remainder to the next page.  Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is quite possible. The **KeepTogether** property of the textbox defaults to true, and is what keeps the textbox from splitting into more than one section. To get your textbox to wrap to the next page, just set **KeepTogether** to false. (Note that you have to use the *Property Window* (F4), not the *TextBox Properties...* dialog box.)

Comment: I was slow to notice this answer. It solves the issue well.  Thanks.

Comment: You deserve a  Noble prize +1

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where a Tablix Text field was not wrapping when the text exceeded the fixed column width.

The following combination of text box settings worked for me.

**Solution Explorer Properties**

Select tablix **Text Box** field > view the Solution Explorer **Properties** window

- Set CanGrow = True (to allow the height to increase)
- Set KeepTogether = True (to stop a line break from being added)

Right click the Tablix Text Box field and click **Text Box Properties** context menu item

**Under the Text Box Properties dialog**

[image: Microsoft Report Viewer 2019 Text Box Properties Dialog]

1. Click **General** tab > under the **Sizing options** header, tick **Allow height to increase**
2. Click **Alignment** tab > then under the **Padding options** header set margins 2mm or less
3. Click **OK** to confirm settings

**Set Placeholder properties**

1. Right click placeholder text inside a text box field and click **Placeholder Properties** from context menu
2. Click **General** tab > then under the **Markup type** header

- Select ***"None - Plain text only"*** for PDF output

or

- Select ***"HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles"*** for webpage output

3. Click **OK** to confirm settings

[image: Microsoft Report Viewer 2019 Placeholder Properties Dialog]

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible.

My work around is to split the text up into an array, by paragraphs and use the list control with a text box.

Comment: Aww that's no fair. I'm having this trouble except with subreports rendering in a table row. If the subreport won't fit on the remainder of the page, then it just page breaks it. Its the most annoying thing ever.